# how to fix a when code throw a same value all the time

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
 public int GetStudentId()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(Id)+1 from Student_Records",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 1;
        }
```

And the problem here is program always throw value 1 there are multiple rows in database

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense: [`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) returns [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.8) - why would you expect it to have a property `Text`?

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: The exception doesn't just tell you that "*something* bad happened". It also tells you exactly what went wrong. Print/inspect the exception.

Comment: @esqew kind of where I was going.  The above code is going to throw an exception everytime and return 1

Comment: If you don't know what the problem is, then why are you throwing away the exception details that would give you that information?

Comment: Comments above are correct; you're throwing away the exception that would tell you what's gone wrong (change that catch clause to print out the exception message (and optionally stacktrace)  `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}`

Comment: Also, where does `txtID` come from?

Answer (score 3):

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) is supposed to return only the count of the rows affected by the query.
In your case it is always 1.

You need to call [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) to get back that MAX value

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(Id)+1 from Student_Records",con);
int maxId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

// This line seems to be unrelated to the code above
// return Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
// You can return the maxId 
return maxId;
```

Also consider that reading the MAX value of a certain field is very weak when you have more than one user inserting records in that table.
It seems that you need to set your *Id* column with the IDENTITY = True at the database level and then read the last inserted Id with SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() from your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

> "*how to fix a when code throw a same value all the time"*

The first step to debugging issues like these should probably be to remove a `try/catch` block that ignores the exception and just returns a hard-coded value for all exceptions. You have effectively blinded yourself to determining what the issue is:

```
public int GetStudentId()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(Id)+1 from Student_Records", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
}
```

Now when you run the code, you will see the exception message and be able to take appropriate action. If the exception is something you can fix in code (for example using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convet.ToInt32`, or using the result of the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` to return the student id), then you can fix it and continue.

You can also add some validation to the method, to try to avoid an exception:

```
public int GetStudentId()
{
    // Validate connection
    if (con == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(con));
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(Id)+1 from Student_Records", con);
    return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

If the exception is something you can't handle in code (for example, `con` is invalid and you don't control the database connection), then you can add a `catch` for the specific exception being thrown and return a well-known value, or log an appropriate error message (or whatever you want to do in that case) and optionally `throw;` after that, so the caller also receives the exception.

```
public int GetStudentId()
{
    try
    {
        // Validate connection
        if (con == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(con));
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(Id)+1 from Student_Records", con);
        return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        // Return a well-known error code that a caller understands (if appropriate)
        return -1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the exception
        Debug.WriteLine(e);

        // Re-throw the exception so program can continue - we
        // don't know what to do here, but maybe the caller will
        throw;
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/) for more information on how to handle exceptions.